# How to route Rails URLS with controller & action but no parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

new rails user here.

I have a rails project that I want to accept a controller and an action, but no parameters. At the moment, the (default) scaffolding-created controller returns the 'show' command whenever I enter an action with no a parameters unless it's the "new" action. If I add a def to the category_controller.rb file and try to visit that url, I get a "couldn't find category with ID=testaction". Any ideas what I'm missing?

Potentially relevant code below.

Many thanks

URL entered: http://0.0.0.0:3000/categories/testaction

```
# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.xml
  def index
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @categories }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.xml
  def testaction
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
    end
  end


  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.xml
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
    end
  end



  # GET /categories/new
  # GET /categories/new.xml
  def new
    @category = Category.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @category }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.xml
  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@category, :notice => 'Category was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category, :status => :created, :location => @category }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /categories/1
  # PUT /categories/1.xml
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to(@category, :notice => 'Category was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @category.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.xml
  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(categories_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end

# Routes.rb
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :categories

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   map.connect 'products/:id', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   map.purchase 'products/:id/purchase', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'purchase'
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   map.resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   map.resources :products, :member => { :short => :get, :toggle => :post }, :collection => { :sold => :get }

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   map.resources :products, :has_many => [ :comments, :sales ], :has_one => :seller

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   map.resources :products do |products|
  #     products.resources :comments
  #     products.resources :sales, :collection => { :recent => :get }
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     admin.resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # map.root :controller => "welcome"

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
  # Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
  # consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:actoin'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end


# Error Message
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#show

Couldn't find Category with ID=testaction

RAILS_ROOT: /home/john/Websites/sandbox/testnoparams
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1616:in `find_one'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1599:in `find_from_ids'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
/home/john/Websites/sandbox/testnoparams/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:28:in `show'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1616:in `find_one'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:1599:in `find_from_ids'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
/home/john/Websites/sandbox/testnoparams/app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:28:in `show'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:67:in `process'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:38:in `run'
/home/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"testaction"}

Show session dump

--- 

Response

Headers:

{"Content-Type"=>"",
 "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a typo in your default routes, which I normally remove anyway :)

```
map.connect ':controller/:actoin'
```

should be

```
map.connect ':controller/:action'
```

To explicitly allow the action to work:

```
map.resources :categories, :collection => {:testaction => [:get, :post]}
```

the [:get, :post] should be replaced with the preferred method of pulling the url.  It can be an array of options or a singular symbol.

references: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html